# R: Check if a date is valid

Tags: r, date

Assume a date specified as three integers: year, month, day

The year is a 4 digit integer (such as 2020), the month ranges over 1-12, the day over 1-31.

I'm looking for a simple function (call it checkdate) that can check whether a date is valid, returning TRUE if valid and FALSE if not valid.

For example, checkdate(2008, 2, 29) would return TRUE because 2008 was a leap year.

On the other hand checkdate(2009, 2, 29) would return FALSE because 2009 was not a leap year.

checkdate(2009, 6, 31) would return FALSE because June has only 30 days.

Etc.

UPDATE

Based on Dirk's answer, below, here is a function that does what I asked:

```
    checkdate = function(y, m, d) {
        #y: A year, not abbreviated to 2 digits.
        #m: An integer in the range 1-12.
        #d: An integer in the range 1-31.

        #Convert to an R Date object.
        #If the date is not valid, NA is returned.
        dt = as.Date(paste(y, m, d, sep='-'), optional=TRUE)

        ifelse(is.na(dt), FALSE, TRUE)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just try to parse it:

```
R> days <- 28:31
R> dates <- paste0("2020-02-", days)
R> as.Date(dates)
[1] "2020-02-28" "2020-02-29" NA           NA          
R>
```

This shows that in 2020, Feb 28 and 29 existed (leap year) but not 30 and 31.

From you three vectors you could use `sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02", y, m, d)` to create a vector of text inputs to parse.

Comment: Your solution works if I use the argument optional=TRUE in the call to as.Date. Otherwise, an error is generated.

Comment: Both solutions, by Ronak and Dirk, are nice. I'm putting a check on Dirk's answer because it doesn't require the use of a third party package--just base R.

Comment: What version of R do you run? I have use the base function `as.Date()` for a bazillion years and never needed to protect for/from the NA.  I can't reproduce what you say here. My example was from a standard "live" session (in R 4.0.1).

Comment: With R 4.2.1 giving `as.Date("2022-02-29")` produces the error `Error in charToDate(x) :  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. The error goes away if you add a valid date (e.g. `as.Date(c("2022-02-28", "2022-02-29"))` or if you give the format (e.g. `as.Date("2022-02-29", format = "%Y-%m-%d")`)

Comment: help(as.Date) explains the behaviour seen by PD Schloss:
 format:  character string. If not specified, it will try tryFormats one by one on the first non-NA element, and give an error if none works. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime() whose help page describes available conversion specifications.

Also, pre-pending with !is.na( ) answers the OP need (checkdate)

Comment: Note that I am unsure when the `tryFormats()` was added -- possibly after I wrote the answer but it *certainly* did not exist a few years ago when I started to work on `anytime` which IIRC was the first to "invent" that idea of cycling through many more formats and brought it to R.  That said, giving a format _always_ existed as an obvious option to `as.Date()` et al.  It is just _tedious_ to do.  Hence `anydate()` from the `anytime` package for me for most uses.

Answer (score 3):

Try to convert the inputs to date if it fails return `FALSE`.

```
checkdate <- function(y, m, d) {
    tryCatch(lubridate::is.Date(as.Date(paste(y, m, d, sep = '-'))), 
             error = function(e) return(FALSE))
}

checkdate(2009, 6, 31)
#[1] FALSE
checkdate(2009, 2, 29)
#[1] FALSE
checkdate(2008, 2, 29)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation for is.Date. Is this, perhaps, your own personal function? Or from a library that needs to be installed?

Comment: @Argent: is.Date is in the lubridate package

Comment: This functions fails in some corner cases. More explicit checks on automatic type conversion are needed. See:

checkdate(2009, 6, "1+2"); checkdate(2009, 6, "1 blah blah")  # returns both true as "2009-06-01"

Comment: However, the OP said "Assume a date specified as three integers: year, month, day". I just note that, working with date entries made by students, I'm often surprised and need a stronger validation.

Comment: Having an explicit format = "%Y-%m-%d" is mandatory, otherwise this returns true: checkdate(y = 12, m = 10, d = 2023)  #it detects 2023 as the year. Still, this is not enough because as.Date truncates strings: as.Date (paste(10, 10, 2023, sep = '-'), format = "%Y-%m-%d"  ) # returns  "10-10-20" which is "a valid date"

Answer (score 0):

Base R using @Ronak Shah's logic:

```
checkdate <- function(y, m, d) {
  tryCatch(inherits(as.Date(paste(y, m, d, sep = '-')), "Date"), 
           error = function(e) return(FALSE))
}
checkdate(2015, 12, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safer function:

```
checkdate <- function(y, m, d, min.year = NA, max.year = NA, recycle = TRUE) {
  if (!recycle){
    y_length <- length(y)
    m_length <- length(m)
    d_length <- length(d)
    if (y_length != m_length | d_length != m_length ){
      stop("The y, m and d vectors provided do not have the same length.")
    }
  }
  
  dates <- paste(y, m, d, sep = "-")
  # Accepts numbers and characters, but explicitly check conversion
  
  !is.na(as.numeric(y)) &
  
  # These 2 lines of code are optional but useful (with min.year=1900, reject "23" as we think "2023" is meant)
    (is.na(min.year) | as.numeric(y) >= min.year ) &  
    (is.na(max.year) | as.numeric(y) <= max.year ) & 
  !is.na(as.numeric(m)) & as.numeric(m) > 0 & as.numeric(m) < 13 &
  !is.na(as.numeric(d)) & as.numeric(d) > 0 & as.numeric(d) < 32 &
  !is.na(as.Date(dates,
                 format = "%Y-%m-%d",
                 optional = TRUE # indicating to return NA (instead of signalling an error)
                 )
         )
}

# Possible uses:
checkdate(0:40, 0:40, 0:40)
checkdate(0:40, 0:40, 0:40, min.year = 2000)
checkdate("2023", 0:40, 0:40, min.year = 2000)
checkdate("2023", 0:40, 0:40, recycle = F)
```

This is much safer than the other answers.
It will work with 3 vectors y, m, d (contrary to Ronak's answer); it recycles them if needed (we can check vector lengths with recycle=F to prevent this). It accepts strings and numbers.
It will not accept "10-11-12" or "10-11-123456789". Note that, a bit surprisingly:

```
as.Date (paste(10, 11, 2023, sep = '-'), format = "%Y-%m-%d" )
[1]  "10-11-20" # is "a valid date" (!)
```

But this is not too surprising: as.Date() was not designed to be a validation function but a function converting valid inputs. We need to be more careful for validation.

The min.year, max.year options and related lines of code are optional but are, in my view, useful in some contexts; they define a valid range for the year. With min.year=1900, we reject "23" as we think "2023" was meant.

Comment: A big thank you to my students who provided me with a huge set a strings manually entered in a form, to be checked. Just for fun, if other form fields are "A movie" or "A song" and data entry is mixed up, then these are "valid" dates: `as.Date (paste( 10, 5, "2001: A Space Odyssey", sep = '-'), format = "%d-%m-%Y" ); as.Date (paste( 10, 5, "99 Luftballons", sep = '-'), format = "%d-%m-%Y" )` : will returns "2001-05-10";  "99-05-10"